# insert a list into a list of objects

Tags: python

In python, I have a class that contains a list as one of its members.

```
class fan_details:
    name = ""
    previous_addresses = []
    age = 0


fans = []

x.name = "Joe Blow"
x.previous_address.append("4, seaview rd")
x.age = 42;
fans.append(x)

x.previous_address.pop(0)

x.name = "Jimmy Flag"
x.previous_address.append("21, Main Street")
x.age = 33;
fans.append(x)

print fans[0].previous_address
print fans[1].previous_address
```

The two last print statements would print out "21, Main Street". It looks like the append() is like a pointer in C as the fans[0].previous address is the same as fans[1].previous address.

Is there a way of keeping fans[0].previous_address to "4, seaview rd"?

Please bear with me as I am a noob in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few problems:

1. spelling errors (previous_addresses vs previous_address)
2. you were not initializing the "self", in other words, when you request a new fan_details object, you were not creating new fan_details objects
3. related to #2, you were not calling for the new object to be created. You need two objects to be created for this example.
4. you were popping the address of your fan_details object, but because fans[0] and fans[1] pointed to the same object you were basically overwriting all the values of fans[0], and creating two references to it.

fixed code:

```
class fan_details:
    #you need to initialize and define the object:
    def __init__(self, name="", previous_address = None, age = 0):
        self.name = name
        if previous_address is None:
            self.previous_addresses = []
        else:
            self.previous_addresses = [previous_address]
        self.age = age


fans = []
x = fan_details()
x.name = "Joe Blow"
x.previous_addresses.append("4, seaview rd")
x.age = 42;
fans.append(x)
#a python object is mutable!!! This means that "x" and fans[0] point to the same
#python object. Lets create a new python object:
x = fan_details(name = "Jimmy Flag", previous_address="21, Main Street", age=33)
#this line above is really important! Note that now we can initialize an object on one line :-)
fans.append(x)    
print fans[0].previous_addresses
print fans[1].previous_addresses
```

Comment: Don't take mutable objects as defaults to python function. As it is, you'll share the list between different fan_details objects.

Comment: whoops! I had that right and then I messed it up. fixed.

Comment: Answer accepted. Thanks for the tip for using self.

Answer (score 1):

Your original class was not using `self` so all the variables were bound to the class definition and shared across all instances.

Following piece of code is defining `__init__` method serving as constructor.

```
class FanDetails():
    def __init__(self, name="", previous_address=None, age=0):
        self.name = name
        self.previous_addresses = []
        if previous_address:
            self.previous_addresses.append(previous_address)
        self.age = age
```

Prepare list of fans:

```
fans = []
```

and now the trick: create an instance of FanDetails for John:

```
john = FanDetails("Joe Blow", "4, seaview rd", 42) 
fans.append(john)
```

and do the same for Jimmy:

```
jimmy = FanDetails("Jimmy Flag", "21, Main Street", 33) 
fans.append(jimmy)
```

Key difference from your original code is, these john and jimmy instances live independently, each having `self` value not being shared across all instances, but being root of instance privacy.

Finally check, that these two guys really do not share more, than reasonable:

```
print fans[0].previous_addresses
print fans[1].previous_addresses
```

You shall see:

```
['4, seaview rd']
['21, Main Street']
```

Comment: Did you really mean append in the constructor? or extend?

Comment: @WinstonEwert My code is fully functional, so I meant `append` as I am adding just one item.

Comment: My bad, I read "previous_address" as "previous_addresses"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have three problems:

1. a typo
2. a need to instantiate `x` as an instance of your `class`
3. No need to `pop` anything if you want to keep these things as a history

my changes in the code would then look like:

```
class fan_details:
    name = ""
    previous_addresses = []
    age = 0


fans = []

x = fan_details()    

x.name = "Joe Blow"
x.previous_addresses.append("4, seaview rd") # <--- You had x.previous_address.append("4, seaview rd")
x.age = 42;
fans.append(x)

# x.previous_address.pop(0)

x = fan_details()    
x.name = "Jimmy Flag"
x.previous_addresses.append("21, Main Street") # <--- You had x.previous_address.append("21, Main Street")
x.age = 33;
fans.append(x)

print fans[0].previous_addresses  # add the 'es'
print fans[1].previous_addresses  # add the 'es'
```

You need to be consistent in the variable name you used in your class definition and the name you use when accessing it.

Comment: You are right, that there was typo. But this does not solve the problem. If you run the code, you will probably crash on first line using `x.name` as it is not know at that place and if you somehow bind it to fan_details class, it will still not print different addresses, as they are stored as so called class attributes and not as instance ones.

Answer (score 0):

List is mutable object so it won't allocate new memory... Copy x ... If iterating ... If not then use different variable...

Suggestion... Please provide complete code (relevant to question )